# Figuring out an array using powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

I'm trying to create an array that will remove files from the destination path and then copy from the source path to the destination path. I've created a .txt document on the build server with a list of files with their relative path. When I run the below block of code it's removing all contents in folder B and copy Folder A(without any contents) to Folder B.

This is what I'm running

```
$files = get-content "C:\files.txt"
foreach ($filepath in $files)
{
    $source = '\\Server1\Folder A' + $filepath
    $dest = '\\Server2\Folder B' + $filepath
    foreach ($removefile in $dest)
    {
       rd $removefile -recurse -force
    }
    foreach ($addfile in $source)
    {
        cp $addfile -destination $dest
    }
}
```

Soda,

I've tried your suggestion but it's trying to remove from/copy to the incorrect directory.

Code:

```
$targetList = Get-Content "C:\MCSfiles.txt"

foreach ($target in $targetList) {

    $destPath = Join-Path "\\Server2\MCSWebTest" $target
    $destFiles = Get-ChildItem $destPath

    foreach ($file in $destFiles) {
       Remove-Item $file -Recurse -Force
    }

    $sourcePath = Join-Path "\\Server1\WebSites\McsWeb2" $target
    $sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem $sourcePath

    foreach ($file in $sourceFiles) {
        Copy-Item $file -Destination $destPath
    }
}
```

Error:

> Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\MCSTest\workspace\App_Code' because it does not exist.
>   At C:\Users\SVC-VI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins5893875881898738781.ps1:9 >char:1
>   9
>   +        Remove-Item <<<<  $file -Recurse -Force
>      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program >File...kspace\App_Co 
>     de:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Remov 
>     eItemCommand
>
> Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\MCSTest\works
>   pace\App_Code' because it does not exist.
>   At C:\Users\SVC-VI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins5893875881898738781.ps1:16 >char:
>   18
>   +         Copy-Item <<<<  $file -Destination $destPath
>      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program >File...kspace\App_Co 
>     de:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyI 
>     temCommand

Soda,

Neither of the suggestions work. It's still removing everything in the destination directory and adding the source directory folder to the destination directory without files.  I'm a little lost here.

Comment: Any new error message?

Answer (score 0):

1. you are missing backslashes in your paths, use `Join-Path` to build your strings to avoid that (*or* maybe leading backslashes are included in `files.txt`)
2. you iterate on `$dest` and `$source` but these are strings, not file collections, which you should be able to retrieve with `Get-ChildItem $dest` and `Get-ChildItem $source`, for instance

Also, for readability, you should not use aliases in scripts (`rd` and `cp`)

PS: I believe your script produces errors, you should include them in your question ([you can edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46203299/edit))

EDIT regarding comments:

Try this (untested, remove `-WhatIf`'s to process):

```
$targetList = Get-Content "D:\files.txt"

foreach ($target in $targetList) {

    $destPath = Join-Path "D:\destination" $target
    Remove-Item $destPath -Recurse -Force -WhatIf

    $sourcePath = Join-Path "D:\source" $target
    Copy-Item $sourcePath -Destination $destPath -Recurse -WhatIf

}
```

**EDIT2: I have corrected and simplified the code above, my logic was slightly off.**

This could even be simpler, and better, to group remove statements and run them before the copy statements, like:

```
$targetList = Get-Content "D:\files.txt"

#remove all
$targetList | ForEach-Object {
    Remove-Item (Join-Path "D:\destination" $_) -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
}

#copy all
$targetList | ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item (Join-Path "D:\source" $_) (Join-Path "D:\destination" $_) -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
}
```

Both snippets have been tested with a sample folder structure.

Just for the sake of completeness, the error you got with my first attempt was due to passing the `$file` objects to the processing cmdlets, instead of full paths (`$file.FullName`).

Comment: The leading backslashes are in included in files.txt.  The first thing that happens is it removes everything under \Server2\Folder B and then starts throwing errors where it can't find a path to remove.

Remove-Item : Cannot remove item \\LTR1MCS04\MCSWebTest: The process cannot acc
ess the file '\\Server2\Folder B' because it is being used by another process

Remove-Item : Cannot find path '\\Server2\Folder B\bin\filname.dll' because it 
does not exist.

I'm not exactly sure where I would add the Get-ChildItem commands.

Comment: @Kerry I have edited my answer and added an example solution. If you get errors, please include them in the question with code or quote formatting (for readability).

Comment: I appreciate all your help, I've edited my question with the code and errors received.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are trying to loop too many times. The outer loop processes the files one at a time. There should be no inner loop. Also, you aren't validating the file exists before issuing a deletion.

```
$files = Get-Content "C:\test.txt"
$source_base="C:\TEMP\source\"
$dest_base="C:\TEMP\dest\"

foreach ($filepath in $files)
{
    $source = $source_base + $filepath
    $dest = $dest_base + $filepath

    if(Test-Path $dest) {rd $dest -recurse -force}
    cp $source -destination $dest
}
```